# How to write presend script in declarative jenkins pipeline

Tags: email, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

I am trying to send HTML file in email body itself (not attachment). I have written Jenkins declarative pipeline as follows

```groovy
post {
        always {
            presendScript: "def reportPath=build.getWorkspace().child("target/serenity-summary.html")
            msg.setContents(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html")"
            emailext attachmentsPattern: "Serenity_Test_Results${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.zip" , 
            body: "${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}  More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL}Unzip the attached document and click on index.html to view complete test results",
            subject: "API Testing: Jenkins Job Results - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Failed",
            mimeType: 'text/html',to: "xyz@abc.com"
            }


}
```

I am getting error as follows

```
WorkflowScript: 30: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 30, column 102.
   target/serenity-summary.html")
                                 ^

1 error
```

I need to attach the HTML file to email body itself and I need proper presend script in post section.

Comment: You have a problem with the quotes in your string, look at the formatting

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a wrong usage of pipeline step `emailext`. You can try as following.

```
post {
  always {

    emailext(
        to: "xyz@abc.com",
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        attachmentsPattern: "Serenity_Test_Results${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.zip",
        subject: "API Testing: Jenkins Job Results - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Failed",
        presendScript: 'def reportPath=build.getWorkspace().child("target/serenity-summary.html");msg.setContents(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html")',         
        body: "${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}  " + 
              "More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL}Unzip the attached document and click on index.html to view complete test results"

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: After I adopted above changes, I am getting below error                                   WorkflowScript: 30: Expected a step @ line 30, column 27.
              presendScript: """def reportPath=build.getWorkspace().child("target/serenity-summary.html")
                             ^

1 error

Comment: Now I am getting below error  :  [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] emailext
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: jenkins for class: groovy.lang.Binding
 at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:264)
 at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:288)

Comment: The error means you used undefined or unaccessable variable in groovy statement. `currentBuild` and `env` are global variable. I guess the issue comes from `build.getWorkspace()` in presendScript, you can comment this line and try again. If the issue does not come from this line, you need to remove `${env.xxxx}` and  `${currentBuild.xxx}` one by one until find the issue one.

Comment: My script as follows: post {
        always { 
            emailext(
        to: "xyz@abc.com",
        mimeType: 'text/html',
        attachmentsPattern: "Serenity_Test_Results_ItemService_${env.BUILD_NUMBER}.zip",
        subject: "API Testing: Jenkins Job Results - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} ",
        presendScript: "msg.setContents(\"target/index.html\", \"text/html\")",         
        body: "Body text here"
) 
   }
}

Comment: Getting error as follows :groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setContents() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [target/index.html, text/html]
Possible solutions: setContent(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String), getContent(), setContent(javax.mail.Multipart), setContentID(java.lang.String), getContentID(), setContentMD5(java.lang.String)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:153)

Comment: the error said your given parameter for `msg.setContents(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)` is wrong type.  Remove `msg.setContents(reportPath.readToString(), "text/html")` and give a try.